# what exception can I use for general network problems?

Tags: c#

In my case server is not available and so I can not read data for client and so I want to throw an Exception.
What Exception should I throw?
I don't want to create my own exception class for such situation, because there are a lot of different situations in program.

Probably there are some kind of "general" exception, like "NetworkProblem" or even just "Problem" or something?

I don't need anything specific, just an exception with message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like an [`IOException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception.aspx) to me. There *may* be a more explicit network-related exception, but I'm not sure. `IOException` is at least a reasonable start...

Answer (score 3):

you can try [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx).

**EDIT**:
Since the WebException is derived from InvalidOperationException it is not appropriate to use WebException. May be it can be IOException like Jon Skeet told, till there is an appropriate inbuild one.

Comment: Why is using a derived exception a bad idea? WebException's definition looks like it matches the original poster's desire perfectly ("The exception that is thrown when an error occurs while accessing the network through a pluggable protocol.").